# How do I reserve space on the stack for a non-default constructible?

Tags: c++, allocation, default-constructor

I would basically write the following piece of code. I understand why it can't compile.

```
A instance; // A is a non-default-constructable type and therefore can't be allocated like this

if (something)
{
    instance = A("foo"); // use a constructor X
}
else
{
    instance = A(42); // use *another* constructor Y
}

instance.do_something();
```

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour *without* involving heap-allocation?

Comment: Did you also provide a copy constructor and an assignment operator for `A`? Also for this case you should better have getter/setter functions for your class attributes, and have a default constructor.

Comment: The easiest solution seems to be using a pointer. Is there a reason you need it to be on the stack?

Comment: Push it into a vector?

Comment: You can't do `A instance("");`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are better, cleaner ways to solve the problem than explicitly reserving space on the stack, such as using a conditional expression.

However if the type is not move constructible, or you have more complicated conditions that mean you *really* do need to reserve space on the stack to construct something later in two different places, you can use the solution below.

The standard library provides the `aligned_storage` trait, such that `aligned_storage<T>::type` is a POD type of the right size and alignment for storing a `T`, so you can use that to reserve the space, then use placement-new to construct an object into that buffer:

```
std::aligned_storage<A>::type buf;
A* ptr;
if (cond)
{
  // ...
  ptr = ::new (&buf) A("foo");
}
else
{
  // ...
  ptr = ::new (&buf) A(42);
}
A& instance = *ptr;
```

Just remember to destroy it manually too, which you could do with a `unique_ptr` and custom deleter:

```
struct destroy_A {
  void operator()(A* a) const { a->~A(); }
};
std::unique_ptr<A, destroy_A> cleanup(ptr);
```

Or using a lambda, although this wastes an extra pointer on the stack ;-)

```
std::unique_ptr<A, void(*)(A*)> cleanup(ptr, [](A* a){ a->~A();});
```

Or even just a dedicated local type instead of using `unique_ptr`

```
struct Cleanup {
  A* a;
  ~Cleanup() { a->~A(); }
} cleanup = { ptr };
```

Comment: Okay, this is much better than my weak placement-new attempt.

Comment: Who is going to call a destructor after placement constructor?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yeah, it avoids potential alignment problems if the `char` buffer isn't suitably aligned

Comment: I did. It's a manual conditional expression/lambda, which is just dumb. juanchopanza seems the be the only one noticing the obvious, language-provided solution.

Comment: @Puppy, the question asks how to reserve space on the stack, so that's what I answered. If the type is move-constructible and a conditional expression would work, that's what the OP should use, but if the two branches of the condition require multiple statements then the `aligned_storage`+placement-new solution still works.

Comment: If they require multiple statements then that's what a lambda is for. The conditional expression also reserves space on the stack, it just does it in a way that's clearly safe, correct, and expressive, doesn't leave local variables littering up the scope, doesn't require manual duplication at each use site, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want to do this more than once, you  can use a helper function:

```
A do_stuff(bool flg)
{
  return flg ? A("foo") : A(42);
}
```

Then

```
A instance = do_stuff(something);
```

Otherwise you can initialize using a conditional operator expression<sup>*</sup>:

```
A instance = something ? A("foo") : A(42);
```

---

<sup>* This is an example of how the conditional operator is not "just like an `if-else`".</sup>

Comment: Then it has to be copy-constructable.

Comment: @user3528438 Or move-constructible. But OP doesn't have requirements re. either of those.

Comment: And if it's truly a one-off function, it can be a lambda.

Comment: @Angew Or just `A instance = something ? A("foo") : A(42);`

Answer (score 3):

In some simple cases you may be able to get away with this standard C++ syntax:

```
A instance=something ? A("foo"):A(42);
```

You did not specify which compiler you're using, but in more complicated situations, this is doable using the `gcc` compiler-specific extension:

```
A instance=({
       something ? A("foo"):A(42);
});
```

Comment: More on " complicated situations", please? In what situation doesn't the first form work?

Comment: @user3528438, if you need entire statements before creating the `A` objects. The conditional operator only allows expressions, the GCC extension allows arbitrary blocks.

Comment: @user3528438: You pointed out one problem yourself on juanchopanza's answer: if `A` is not copy-constructible then this code is illegal.

Comment: That's what lambdas are for or even a helper function. And it's move-constructible, scrub.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for placement new, though there are almost certainly simpler solutions you could employ if you revisit your requirements.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(const std::string& str) : str(str), num(-1)  {};
    A(const int num)          : str(""),  num(num) {};

    void do_something()
    {
        std::cout << str << ' ' << num << '\n';
    }

    const std::string str;
    const int num;
};

const bool something = true;   // change to false to see alternative behaviour

int main()
{
    char storage[sizeof(A)];
    A* instance = 0;

    if (something)
        instance = new (storage) A("foo");
    else
        instance = new (storage) A(42);

    instance->do_something();
    instance->~A();
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/883596836a2a9f3a))

This way you can construct the `A` whenever you like, but the storage is still on the stack.

However, you have to destroy the object yourself (as above), which is nasty.

---

**Disclaimer:** My weak placement-new example is naive and not particularly portable. GCC's own Jonathan Wakely posted a much better example of the same idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::experimental::optional<Foo> foo;
if (condition){
  foo.emplace(arg1,arg2);
}else{
  foo.emplace(zzz);
}
```

then use `*foo` for access.  `boost::optional` if you do not have the C++1z TS implementation, or write your own `optional`.

Internally, it will use something like std aligned storage and a `bool` to guard "have I been created"; or maybe a `union`.  It may be possible for the compiler to prove the `bool` is not needed, but I doubt it.

An implementation can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional) or you can use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).